# App to Ensure Healthy Coffee Consumption?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, ios

If I don't drink enough coffee my brain doesn't function.

If I drink too much coffee, I end up over-percolating my brain.

Is there an app that will recommend how much coffee you should consume to keep your consumption at the optimal rate, so that your brain functions but doesn't *over*-function?

Ideally, the app would go so far as to slide back your coffee consumption so that your body doesn't get used to an amount so that it requires more.

Comment: It's pretty off-topic but the amount of caffeine that you can tolerate is highly dependent on your body build and the amount of caffeine you usually have in your body (as resistance build up). So I'd say it's almost impossible to get accurate numbers. But maybe you should try kicking the habit for good, then you wouldn't need it at all after a while.

Comment: @XQYZ I kicked the habit a while ago (like 2 years ago), but I'm having difficulty without it, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: This question is on-topic for Ask Different. It is just a software-recommendation, and we allow plenty of those questions. If you have downvoted because you feel this is off-topic, please consider removing the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: + the fact that the problem is non-trivial from a medical / physiological standpoint makes this _more_ interesting. We all had to endure the fart apps and exploration of how many ways a photo can be taken - now we can hope for apps like this.

Answer (score 1):

so there's an interesting web tool I would recommend: http://chartmyself.com/

You can use it to figure out just how much coffee you're drinking and how much you can get away with not drinking. There are articles on the site to recommend how to not drink too much :)